# How to name a function that copy or rename a file/directory

Tags: functions, higher-order-functions

I have a function

```
function name(src, dest, remove) {
    copy(src, dest);
    if (remove) {
       delete(src);
    }
}
```

What name should I give to that function? Alternatively higher order function like this:

```
function name(remove) {
    if (remove) {
        return function(src, dest) {
           copy(src, dest);
           delete(src);
        };
    } else {
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function breaks the "do one thing" rule which makes it hard to find a simple name. In the first example a parameter is called remove, it should be called rename in order to understand the function with more ease.

Comment: Move? So... moveOrCopy?

Answer (score 7):

Remove the boolean, and have two functions: move, and copy.

Comment: I wanted it to be DRY.

Comment: First and foremost, we should concern ourselves with the quality of the abstraction being provided the consuming clients (even if that is just us), and then worry about implementation details, which includes DRY.  That you're having trouble naming the method is an indication that the abstraction isn't that good.  You might consider providing all three methods, `move`, `copy`, and `moveOrCopy`, and see which ones actually get used.  Further, if `move` calls `copy`, that is quite DRY, i.e. as long as it doesn't implement its own copy.

Comment: DRY is not important here.  Both functions simply call other functions; it's not like you're rampantly copy/pasting large swaths of code (I've seen code-bases that do that).  The purpose of DRY is to prevent that practice, not to prevent you from having good function design because you called a function twice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the hard time naming the function is caused by the evidence that it's violating the [SLA Principle](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction). See also [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Quoting the link:

> All statements of a method **should belong to the same level of
>   abstraction**. If there is a statement which belongs to a lower level of
>   abstraction, it should go to a private method which comprises
>   statements on this level. Doing so will result in smaller methods.

Copy, move and delete are different *abstractions*. Aren't they? They are functions with different *responsibilities*.

As @ErikEidt mentioned, would be easier to find the name, if we apply any of the two principles:

```
function copy(src, dest){
 //...
 return cp;
}

function delete(src){
 //...
}

function move(src, dest){
   var cp = copy(src,dest);
   delete(src);
   return cp;
}

function copyOrMove(src, dest, copy){
   if(copy){
       return copy(src,dest);
   }
   return move(src,dest);
}
```

The last "abstraction" is just encapsulating an `if` statement. It could make sense if we expect to deal often with that disjunctive. The thing is, we see now clearly what it does and what's the possible name.

So, I think, the answer to the question could be:

- **copyOrMove** for the higher level function
- **move** for the lower level function

Despite the number of the functions, we still keep the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle, because we didn't repeat any level of abstraction. So far, we created a new one (*copyOrMove*).

*Note: I kept the functions names given by the OP to make the refactor easier to follow. As usual, it could be improved, for instance, dropping delete(). I kept delete() because I think it's a legit function by itself with a well-defined responsibility/abstraction*

Comment: I like that quote, and the reasoning here.  A corollary, in the reverse, is that if your client has to reach around your abstraction to do something, it is an indication that the abstraction is incomplete.  And an incomplete abstraction leads to tighter implementation coupling as clients try to make up the difference(s).